# cannot create file in azure storage on failure of previous task: The schema definition for action with status code '200' is not valid

Tags: azure-logic-apps, powerapps, power-platform

I am saving a file to azure storage .

If the filename is numeric, it will be saved in DirectoryA, otherwise it will be saved to DirectoryB.

There is no "isNumeric()" function in powerflow, so I am casting the filename as int and if it fails, i am directing the flow to save the file to a different folder.

The issue is, for the task that saves file to azure storage, if i set it to "run on failure of previous task, i get the error:

```
The schema definition for action with status code '200' is not valid. The schema definitions for actions with same status code must match.
```

I cannot find any way around this, and would appreciate any advise or expertise.

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save your response in a variable. Set the variable in different conditional branches multiple times.

And at then end of all actions/branches add "`Respond to PowerApps`" only once in whole FLOW and **use variable in it**.

For more details, you could refer to this [issue](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Respond-to-PowerApps-Error-schema-definition-for-action-with/m-p/273715).